# Is it possible to apply an image map over a embedded image in an email?

Tags: html, html-email, imagemap

I am sending a normal html email message to people using PHP of which the sending is irrelevant to this question. I allow for people to embed images when they send so I got this weird behavior this morning.

When I embed an image, but the image and the HTML contains an image map to link certain parts of the image to actual http links. The image map fails. If the image is not embedded, the image works fine. This also happens just for desktop email clients.

Now, my question is, is that normal behavior or am I doing something wrong?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can. However, if they do not accept HTML emails then they will just see plain-text. I'm sure you've seen an email where the html doesn't get displayed properly.

As I say though, I'm pretty sure you can but I'm not sure how well javascript works in an email client just FYI.

Comment: Javascript does not work in an email client, it gets stripped. An image map is HTML though

Comment: Yeah I realize that the image map is HTML however, I was just mentioning, I didn't know if you wanted to use JS in there too. So I thought I'd bring it up for you.